# Delphi TWebBrowser window.devicePixelRatio property

Tags: delphi, scale, twebbrowser

in our app we use the TWebBrowser component of Delphi to display web content. Now we have a problem if windows has scaled monitors, for example 125% scale. In this case some HTML-controls aren't rendert correctly, because the window.devicePixelRatio property in JavaScript isn't updated but stays on 1, althougt it should be 1.25 on a 125% scaled monitor.

Is there any posibillity to fix this issue? From inside JavaScript it is not possible to changes this value, but maybe from the Delphi side?

Edit: I tried out an embedded chromium and there it works fine. But currently it is not possible to move from ie to chromium.

A sample HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 25px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 4px; overflow: hidden">
            <span style="font-size:10pt; white-space: pre">Long sample text</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Embedded IE the text ist cut of

Comment: Try to run your application at least in IE8 compatibility mode.

Comment: Our application runs with the latest IE11, and we have to do this.

Comment: So you run your application in IE11 compatibility mode?

Comment: Tell me how, then I can try

Comment: [This way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25843958/8041231). If you haven't done this, your app. is running in backwards compatibility IE7 mode. Just beware that IE11 mode is no good for everyone (embedded control behaves different than Internet Explorer; better try IE10 first).

Comment: [There](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx) is no code for compatibility mode. I also tried out some different codes, but nothing changed

Comment: Why code? It's a setting by which your `TWebBrowser` starts working in mode that you set (not in default IE7 mode). Optionally [you can add this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183405/8041231) to your HTML (that should run the site in the latest browser mode, which in your case is IE11).

Comment: Yes, it is a setting, and for the setting you need a numeric code like 11000 for IE 11. And changing HTML is not an option.

Comment: I'm aware of it (IE9 should be enough I guess, but let's run it in IE11 mode). More I'm wondering if it helped. Did it help? Does `TWebBrowser` control reflect DPI changes when running in IE11 mode?

Comment: As i said, nothing changed

Comment: Is the web HTML contents in your control? Can you show a sample HTML?

Comment: The HTML is not under our control. And I think that I'm not allowed to share sample code.

Comment: I just rebuilt the Element with the problem and added a sample above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it is obsolete, you will find that enabling [FEATURE_96DPI_PIXEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330738(v=vs.85).aspx) for your application will return the correct pixelratio:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_96DPI_PIXEL
                     yourapplication.exe = (DWORD) 00000001
```

The recommended way is to enable the [DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10505990/800214) flag.

Comment: I can't test now, but doesn't `X-UA-Compatible` set to `IE=edge` should take care of any compatibility issue? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183405/937125

Comment: Thanks for the info:)

Comment: Using an obsolet method is not an option. And for the other flag I can't find any sample or something similar, and I did not make it work.

Comment: @Sumafu, just add the flag to the registry, it will work (as I tried it). IE is obsolete anyway

Comment: Ok, but where in the registry?

Comment: Thank you, with this it works. And as long as it works with Windows 10 and latest IE, it should also works in earlier versions :D

Comment: @Sumafu, small sidenote if you are certain that your users are on IE9 or higher, you can also enable FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING for better performance (depends how heavy the site is you are presenting)